# Data storage on same guest as vCenter?

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

My VMware vCenter stores all its data in a SQL Server database.  The database server resides on the same VM as vCenter itself.  This means that vCenter is able to run independently of other servers, which seems like a good thing.  However I am not 100% sure.

Can anyone outline the pros and cons of this approach, and if strongly in favour of something else, please share details.

*I'm currently on ESX 3.5, but will shortly be upgrading to 4.1 - a point at which it seems a good idea to readdress the previous decision*

Comment: I'd be interested in this myself. This is the configuration that we're currently running to allow our environment to recover to a complete power failure, but I'd be interested in other opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Well the Pros include know g that a snapshot gets your VC and DB quieced together plus it should be pretty fast to a point (8 vCPUs max for all functions). Cons include that it'll be a little harder to separate functions in the future if you start hitting performance limits, it makes clustering your DB a little more fragile and any VM reboots will take longer as it'll have more to load. Otherwise why not, certainly if you have comparatively small environment (<100 hosts or so).